# How to automatically close the Debug Output Window in PTVS?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013

I am using the PTVS package on MSVS 2013 Express to develop and run my Python scripts. I am using the `Start` button (<kbd>F5</kbd>) to run the script. The script uses the TCP/IP stack to communicate with an external program running in the background. The last lines in my script are:

```
del SWLink
sys.exit()
```

where `SWLink` is the comm object that was defined.

While running the script, a terminal (command) window is opened where some messages are echoed, including my print() messages. When the script ends, the terminal waits for a key press to close and return control to the IDE.

**How should I finish my script so that the terminal closes automatically?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to automatically close the Debug Output Window, open:

`DEBUG` -> `Options and Settings...` -> `Python Tools` -> `Debugging`

and uncheck the `Wait for input when process exits normally` and `Wait for input when process exits abnormally` checkboxes.

UPDATE: I don't know why, but this only works *sometimes*??!